# Getting closed implementation type inside Autofac's WithParameter

Tags: c#, entity-framework, autofac

I'm trying to register generic repository to use specific context based on entity custom attribute. Below is what i have

Globax.asax

```
//data layer
foreach (var database in DatabaseManager.Databases)
{
    builder.Register<IDbContext>(c => new CodesObjectContext(database.ConnectionString))
        .As<IDbContext>()
        .Named<IDbContext>(database.Alias)
        .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
}

builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(EfRepository<>)).As(typeof(IRepository<>))
    .WithParameter(new ResolvedParameter(
        (pi, ctx) => pi.ParameterType == typeof(IDbContext),
        (pi, ctx) => ctx.ResolveNamed<IDbContext>((
            { Generic Type Of EfRepository}.GetType()
                .GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DatabaseAttribute), true)[0] 
                    as DatabaseAttribute).Name)))
    .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

I cant seem to get here, `{ Generic Type Of EfRepository }`. Is it possible for me to get the current generic type of EfRepository being registered?

Comment: Every closed version of `EfRepository<T>` will have the same `DatabaseAttribute`, so this would always result in the same `Name` for every closed version of `IRepository<T>`. So I don't think what you're trying to do would work at all.

Comment: My comment is not quite on the topic. `DbContext` should be used in short scenarios: you create it, you use it, you call `SaveChanges`, and you dispose it. Pass DbContextFactory in constructors of your repositories. [Details](http://mehdi.me/ambient-dbcontext-in-ef6/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the concrete resolved type using the `DeclaringType` of the parameter info

```
builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(EfRepository<>))
       .As(typeof(IRepository<>))
       .WithParameter(new ResolvedParameter(
               (pi, c) => pi.ParameterType == typeof(IDbContext),
               (pi, c) => c.ResolveNamed<IDbContext>(
                   pi.Member.DeclaringType
                     .GetGenericArguments()[0] 
                     .GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DatabaseAttribute), true)
                     .OfType<DatabaseAttribute>()
                     .First()
                     .Name))) 
       .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

Another solution would be to use the `OnPreparing` pseudo event and inject a new `Parameter`

```
builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(EfRepository<>))
       .As(typeof(IRepository<>))
       .OnPreparing(e => {
           e.Parameters = e.Parameters.Union(
               new[] {
                   new ResolvedParameter(
                       (pi, c) => pi.ParameterType == typeof(IDbContext),
                       (pi, c) => {
                           String databaseName = 
                               pi.Member
                                 .DeclaringType
                                 .GetGenericArguments()[0]              
                                 .GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DatabaseAttribute), true)
                                 .OfType<DatabaseAttribute>()
                                 .FirstOrDefault()
                                 .?Name
                           if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(databaseName)
                           {
                               // TODO
                           }

                           c.ResolveNamed<IDbContext>(databaseName)
                       }
                   )
               });
       })
       .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

You can also create add the OnPreparing event on a custom `Module`. See http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/examples/log4net.html for more information.

Answer (score 0):

I manage to solve it using information from ParameterInfo. Here is my solution:

```
 //data layer
            foreach (var database in DatabaseManager.Databases)
            {
                builder.Register<IDbContext>(c => new CodesObjectContext(database.ConnectionString))
                    .As<IDbContext>()
                    .Named<IDbContext>(database.Alias)
                    .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
            }

        builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(EfRepository<>)).As(typeof(IRepository<>))
            .WithParameter(new ResolvedParameter(
                   (pi, ctx) => pi.ParameterType == typeof(IDbContext),
                   (pi, ctx) => ctx.ResolveNamed<IDbContext>(
                       (pi.Member.DeclaringType.GetGenericArguments()[0] //get generic type
                       .GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DatabaseAttribute), true)[0] as DatabaseAttribute).Name))) //get attribute database name
       .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```